# Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm(), Error in test file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, redux-form

When i run my tests, i get the error:

`Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`

I am mocking a store, so i would think that would take care of injecting redux on the test but, i'm not really sure.

Inside appointments.js I have a component that has a redux form

```
import React from 'react';
... other imports
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import expect from 'expect';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import LoginSection from '../User/LoginSection';
import AppointmentsContainer from './AppointmentsContainer';
import Appointments from './Appointments';
import AppointmentStatus from .../Layout/AppointmentStatus/AppointmentStatusContainer';

jest.mock('./Appointments');
jest.mock('../User/LoginSection');
jest.mock('../Layout/AppointmentStatus/AppointmentStatusContainer');

const store = configureMockStore()({
  form: 'Appointments',
});

const setup = (newProps) => {
  const props = {
    handleSubmit: jest.fn(),
    },
    form: 'appointmentsContainer',
    locale: 'en',
    ...newProps,
  };

  const root = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <IntlProvider {...props}>
        <AppointmentsContainer {...props} />
      </IntlProvider>
    </Provider>
    ,
  );

  const wrapper = root.find(Appointments);

  return {
    root,
    wrapper,
    props,
  };
};

describe('AppointmentsContainer', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
  });
```

Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Its coming from jest syntax cancel it if you dont need